# How to set margin top, bottom of page in print?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to print a special div of page with javascript.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```

and in html page

```
<div id="MainDIV" style="width:700px; min-height: 100%; padding-top: 0; margin-top: 0; padding-right:15px; padding-left: 15px;font-family: 'BYagut' !important">
     // my code
</div>
```

and set css for this page.

```
@page {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

but when I click the print button, there is a large distance from the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). You can set it to "print" and specify the margins in your CSS.

> The @media CSS at-rule lets you specify declarations that depend on the condition of a media query. The rule may be placed at the top level of your code or nested inside any other conditional group at-rule.
>
> print
>
> Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in print preview mode.